# attributes not editable in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

when I select a button in design view, I don't see the attributes menu populating with options and was wondering how to fix this:

[image]

Comment: See the red circle with an exclamation mark? Check that. You probably have a build error you need to fix.

Comment: it looks like you have some problem with the project. Try to build it to see what it is.